# Is $L:\mathbb P_4\to \mathbb{R}$, with $L(p)=p''(0)$, a linear function?

Tags: linear-algebra

Is $L:\mathbb P_4\to \mathbb{R}$, with $L(p)=p''(0)$, a linear function?

My response is -

Yes. We know that the derivative map on $\mathbb{P}_4$ is linear. So the function $M(p) = p''$ is also linear. Evaluating a function at a point is linear: if $f,g$ are functions with domain and codomain the real numbers, the addition rule defined by $(f + g)(x) = f(x) + g(x)$ and the multiplication rule defined by $(rf)(x) = rf(x)$ guarantees that evaluating $f$ at $x = 0$ is a linear operation.

My classmates however disagree. Could someone confirm that I am indeed correct, or point out where my logic went wrong?

Comment: Your logic is fine.... here is something more simple minded.  $L$ takes $p(x)\in \mathbb P_4$ to the coefficient of the $x^2$ term.  And $L(q+p) = L(q)+L(p)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer is correct: you prove that a function is linear as the **composition** or two linear functions : taking the second derivative, then evaluating in $0$.

Of course, there is a different path, by describing the operation with respect to the "canonical" basis $1,x,x^2,x^3,x^4$, where your linear function (a **linear form**, more precisely) is:

$$(ax^4+bx^3+cx^2+dx+e) \  \to \ (12ax^2+6bx+2c) \ \to \ (2c)$$

which can be proven to be linear by exhibiting its $1 \times 5$ matrix:

$$\left(\begin{array}{c}a\\b\\c\\d\\e\end{array}\right)\to \left(\begin{array}{ccccc}0&0&2&0&0\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{c}a\\b\\c\\d\\e\end{array}\right)$$